Google Pixel 8 Pro - Access telephoto lens with CameraX or Camera2 in Android
I am trying to get a camera controller in my app to use the telephoto lens of my Google Pixel 8 Pro.
However, listing the available cameras do only result in list of 1 front and 1 back camera where I am not sure what the back camera exactly is. I expected to have at least two back cameras (one base and one telephoto lens).
Are there any restrictions to access the hardware lenses (more than one) in that case? Does someone have experience?
Best regards
I expect two have at least 2 available camera controller for the back/rear camera when listing available cameras with Camera2 or CameraX plugin in Anroid

I have a Pixel 8 - I am pretty sure that the telephoto is being accessed by the maximum zoom by the cameraX engine. check my tutorial for my app -> you can see the preview not sync when changing the camera by the engine. https://youtu.be/MlEfGOuhQog

The recent Pixel devices implement the logical camera API, so the entire back camera cluster (ultrawide, wide, telephoto sensors) is treated as a single logical camera.  So if you open camera 0, it will automatically switch between camera lenses based on scene conditions and the settings you ask.
If you want to explicitly use the telephoto camera, you can do that by using OutputConfiguration.setPhysicalCameraId for your outputs.  You can get the list of available physical cameras from CameraCharacteristics.getPhysicalCameraIds from camera ID 0's camera characteristics, and identify the telephoto using the focal length of the physical camera's characteristics.
As long as you use just the same camera for all outputs, the capabilities of the camera should be the same as just using the logical camera only.  Using multiple physical cameras at once is less guaranteed due to hardware resource limits, so make sure to verify that the proposed session configuration is actually supported via CameraDevice.isSessionConfigurationSupported.

Can OutputConfiguartion be used with CameraX? I've found other options for SetPhysicalCameraId in CameraX, but they don't seem to have an effect. Thanks Eddy
